# Range variable in vba not accepting pointer based value

Tags: excel, range, vba

`pointer` is base address A8, `ref` is to navigate in the sheet.

Error: `pointer` takes value in cell A8 not the address `$A$8`; even if pointer is set as string it causes "*type mismatch*" in line 5

```
Dim ref As Range, pointer As Range
Dim diff as Integer

Set pointer = Range("A8").Address
Set ref = pointer.Offset(diff, 0)

ref.Value = Date
```

Comment: `Dim pointer as String` if you want to get the `Address`, and `pointer = Range("A8").Address`

Comment: Just `Set pointer = Range("A8")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing different types of data with different types of variables.

Inf your code, you define `Pointer` as Range, so the line `Set pointer = Range("A8").Address` is incorrect, because [Range.Address](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-address-property-excel) returns a string value.

So just replace the line `Set pointer = Range("A8").Address` with `Set pointer = Range("A8")`

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the differences

- `Range("A8")` is of type `Range` and represents cell A8 **with all its properties**.
- `Range("A8").Address` is of type `String` and represents the address of cell A8 which is "$A$8".
- `Range("A8").Value` represents the value of a cell.

So you need to decide what you want.

eg `.Offset(diff, 0)` does only work on a range but not on a address. So you probably meant to use `Set pointer = Range("A8")`. To access the address of `pointer` you can then use `pointer.Address`.